# Factoring out a method appearing across many enums

Tags: java, spring, enums, java-8

I have several enums with a `name` property and a `byName` method which is roughly like this for all of them:

```
public static Condition byName(String name) throws NotFoundException {
    for (Condition c : values()) {
        if (c.name.equals(name)) {
            return c;
        }
    }

    throw new NotFoundException("Condition with name [" + name + "] not found");
}
```

Since the `byName` method is duplicated across different enums, I'd like to factor it out in a single place and avoid duplicated code.

However:

- Enums cannot extend an abstract class
- Java8 interfaces with default methods cannot access the `values()` method

I know this could probably be done with AspectJ, but I'd rather not introduce compile-time weaving for something simple as this, and Spring AOP (which I have at hand since this is a Spring project) only allows binding to existing methods and not adding new ones.

Any other viable solution to add a common method to enums?

Comment: Can't you wrap those enums into another class (one enum per class)... And this class would extend an abstract class with this `byName` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I did in the same situation:

```
public interface EnumWithNames {
    String getName();

    static <E extends EnumWithNames> E byName(Class<E> cls, String name) {
        for (E value : cls.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (Objects.equals(value.getName(), name)) return value;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot identify " + cls.getName() + " value by name " + name);
    }
}

public enum Condition implements EnumWithNames {
    private String name;
    ...

    @Override
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

And when I need to find enum value by name I call:

```
Condition c = EnumWithNames.byName(Condition.class, "Name 1");
```

Note `cls.getEnumConstants()` is the same as `values()`.

Comment: You could even require that `E` is an Enum as well: `<E extends Enum<?> & EnumWithNames>`. This would allow using the `values()` call.

Comment: @Thirler You can narrow the type `T`, but you cannot call the implicit method `values()`.

Comment: Declaring `E` as `<E extends Enum<?> & EnumWithNames>` doesn’t allow calling the `values()` method, but it prevents callers from passing a non-`enum` type for which this method wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I'm a bit late to the party here.. but here is what I have in place for this case:

```
    static interface Nameable {

        static <T extends Enum<T>> T byName(Class<T> clazz, String name) {

           return EnumSet.allOf(clazz)
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> i.name().equals(name))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create some sort of static utility method and use the utility method inside the enum itself. You've still got a little bit of duplication. Not sure of a much better way of doing it.

```
public static T staticByName(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
    for (T c : values()) {
        if (c.name.equals(name)) {
            return c;
        }
    }

    throw new NotFoundException("Condition with name [" + name + "] not found");
}
```

and in the enum

```
public static Condition byName(String name){
    return Utility.staticByName(name, Condition.class);
}
```

Alternately, you could put the items in a map at Enum instantiation to make it a bit more efficient.

Code above is untested, so you would probably have to modify it to work on Enums, but it gets the idea across.

Comment: I think you got a better idea, my solution is pretty useless since you need an instance of the enum. There is just 1 problem, you are calling `values` on nothing.